# Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' after adding multidex to my application

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, classnotfoundexception, dex

This is the continuation of this question: [Unable to merge dex - how to exclude proper jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46983505/unable-to-merge-dex-how-to-exclude-proper-jar)

I have not a typical android project, i am just working on the separate module, which is not connected with activies, fragments, UI etc. in my manifest i am not declaring any Android specifiacions. Here is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.moduleName.sampleName"
>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
</uses-permission>

</manifest>
```

i was having the exception:

> Caused by: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

So, here is what my build.gradle file looks like now:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"


packagingOptions {
    exclude 'protobuf.meta'
}

testOptions {
    unitTests {
        includeAndroidResources = true
    }

}
sourceSets {
    test.java.srcDirs += ['build/generated/source/apt/test/debug']
}

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
 }

}

ext.daggerVersion = '2.11'
ext.roomVersion = '1.0.0-rc1'

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:3.4.2"
kaptTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
kaptAndroidTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"


// RxJava
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'

// Room
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$roomVersion"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:$roomVersion"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$roomVersion"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.51"
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistence.room:testing:$roomVersion"

// Dagger
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$daggerVersion"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:$daggerVersion"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:$daggerVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$daggerVersion"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:$daggerVersion"

implementation 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location2:2.0@aar'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'

//Jackson
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.9.1'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.9.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

}
```

My tests that are in the package 'test' are working fine.

But when i trying to run some test in my androidTest class package i get this:

> Started running tests
>   Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError'
>   Empty test suite.

**To sum up:**

The beginning of this problem is in the link above - i was having large amount of methods after adding jackson library, so i added dex support and this got me to this problem, which i really don't know how to solve - trying to exclude some depenendencies and leave only really important, trying to clean the project, deleting build package. None of them worked. If it is important i am using Kotlin in this module

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add MultiDexApplication in the AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.myapp">
<application
     android:name="com.example.myapp.MyApplication" >
    ...
</application>
```

If you do override the Application class, change it to extend MultiDexApplication (if possible) as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication { ... }
```

[Check this Google official blog here for MultiDex support](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html#mdex-gradle)